# Homebrew with sudo parameters for special packages

Tags: macos, homebrew, sudo

Good morning, I have a quick question.

In some homebrew packages, `sudo` is required during the installation.
Now, I would like to replace this `sudo` with `sudo -H -u layer`.
The reason for this is that we currently do not give admin rights to the normal users on some computers, but the user `layer` has admin rights.

Therefore, I have to give these parameters, are there perhaps env variables that I can use? Or must I set this up in the `/etc/sudoers`

Comment: Can you try to define a function like `sudo() { command sudo -H -u layer "$@"; }` ?